# Android External Storage among mobile brands

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am facing interesting problem. I have discovered, that Samsung in it's own Android phones has two implementations of storage.

**1st:** /sdcard - is internal memory and /sdcard/external_sd is actually inserted memory card

**2nd:** /storage/sdcard0 - is internal memory and /storage/ExtSdCard is actually inserted memory card.

My app needs data to be stored in sd card, so I am facing problem, how to determine, which folder might be sd card link or not. Do you know situation of any other Android maker (LG, HTC, Sony), how to cope with external SD cards and how they are visible in android system?

Comment: you should accept your answers or provide comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really so simple. When you consider your samsung mobiles it is the internal storage that acts as your sdcard.

if you are looking for to save a file in Sdcard, you have to stop hard coding the path like,

```
/mnt/sdcard.. and so.
```

instead use,   `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

This will return the path to your sdcard straight away.

And from there, add  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"your directoryname";`

And this works for all brands not unique to Samsung.

Comment: My question is, in Samsung, if I don't explicitly specify Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory+"/external_sd" it will save it to internal memory, instead of saving to sd card. Same for the second case. So for Samsung it must be sort of hard coded

Comment: Next question is, is externalStorageDirectory my phone returns still the same at LG, HTC, Sony and I have to detect, if it is mounted or the storageDirectory changes, whether I have sd card inserted or not?

Comment: @Andro Selva Finding path for manufacturer provided sdcard is not so simple, OP has asked specifically about the sdcard slots provided by manufacturer there is no API in android to find the path for the external sdcard slot I am not talking about getExternalStorageDirectory() which may or may not be an external card in real sense